# Log a Windows workstation in with user/password from remote

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, automation, remote

There are a bunch of computers I have to log onto guest accounts every once in a while. I prefer having the guests logged in by the time they arrive, so I'd like to log them on in advance.

I used to turn them all on, log them on, and done. But I'd like to automate it as follows:

1. Wake the computers up on lan
2. Log them on via command-line so when they arrive they are logged on and see the desktop

I've already managed to wake them all up via WOL through my batch, but I'm struggling to find a way to log them on without having to do it manually.

Is this possible? The used OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a powershell snip for autologon.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name DefaultUserName -Value "Administrator"
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name DefaultPassword -Value "Password1"
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name AutoAdminLogon -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name ForceAutoLogon -Value 1
```

or via .reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"DefaultUserName"="Administrator"
"DefaultPassword"="Password1"
"AutoAdminLogon"="1"
"ForceAutoLogon"="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

To automate RDP connexion , you can use a great (and free) software called [Remote Desktop Plus](http://www.donkz.nl/)

And use a command line like this one from the command prompt :

```
rdp.exe /v:hostname /u:username /p:password /max
```

Many other features available, check the website !